# Long columns vs Long rows Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, normalization, entity-attribute-value

I am stuck between choosing a way of database table designing. The scenario is that I need to make database of cellphones and tablets specifications. The database can be in two ways...

1- Long columns way, in which I will add each specification field as an individual column which will result in 38 columns, resulting in a complete product specification in just a single row.

2- Long rows way, in which I will ad just 5 columns: `id`, `name`, `value`, `brand`, and `model`, saving each product specification in a name value pair which will result in 38 rows for each specification.

Which way should I go.. and why..?

Comment: This question is a request for discussion, and is inappropriate here. The [faq] indicates that discussion questions are a poor fit for the question and answer design here. Voting to close as not constructive. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The first solution is the more traditional.  The second is called "entity-attribute-value" (EAV).

For most applications, the first is preferable.  For instance, in the second method, all values would have to be the same type.  But one might be the date the product was released, and others might be strings.

The second also results in much clearer queries.  Having to bring together the attributes from dozens of rows to describe a singel model can be inefficient.  At the very least, it results in more cumbersome queries.

Such a data structure also makes it more difficult to do data validation checks and to have foreign key relationships to other tables.

Finally, the EAV approach uses more space.

There are some cases where EAV is quite valuable.  For instance, if you have thousands of attributes and only a few are being used for any given product.  38 columns, though, is quite reasonable for a single table.

Comment: I am trying to make a similar table about companies and their features, company category(1 parent + 3to5 child categories per company) and search tags(10 tags).

It will come around 70to100 columns, but problem is in future i may have around 1 million companies added to it. So it will have around 1 million rows or more. Which will be better in my case. @Gordon Linoff, your reply will be very valuable for me!

Answer (score 0):

The question should be whether you will foresee *any* columns that need to be added in future or whether many columns will not be used.

For your second option, you could go even further:

```
phones: [id], brand, model
attributevalues: [(phone), (name)], value
attributenames: [name]
```

Where `[xx]` is a primary key and `(xx)` is a foreign key.

However, to take advantage of typing, the first is the preferred method.

You could also denormalize it a little and introduce blocks of related attributes in another table and link it up using a 1:1 relationship; you could use this to move lesser used attributes into another table. Note that this is just a space compromise.

Comment: That is not what normalization means.  There is no rule of normalization that would lead you to use Entity-attribute-value.  It's not even a relation.

Comment: @BillKarwin Fair enough, reworded it :)